# How can I handle the primary key of a table with multiple batch inserts?

Tags: sql, multithreading, jakarta-ee, db2

I previously was working on an app that populated the ODS in real time. Every it was determined that all the records for a given table were correct, a sequence object specific to each table's PK would be called to generate the PK. Once returned, it would be stored in a Map for use in FK references on other tables in the same session; it was inserted directly, not auto generated. I understand that the sequence is thread safe, in that 

A friend mentioned that on one of his prior projects at a different company they used batch processing and simply used the range of max index +1 up to the number of rows to be inserted. However, the tables were locked inside one instance of the app, not a cluster.

Say one wanted to support both batch and real-time operations for the same collection of tables. With a stored procedure would it be possible to:

1. Lock a sequence object.
2. Increment it by an parameter for # of rows.
3. Store in a temp variable the last value.
4. Unlock the sequence object.
5. Finally, return the temp variable.

The first problem I have with this idea is that unless the command to lock the sequence can be blocked, there is nothing to prevent this stored procedure from being run multiple times simultaneously. I add the J2E tag in the event someone could provide a better solution that is primarily on the Java side.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Why don't you use real (= DBMS supplied) sequences?

Comment: DB2. The idea is to be able to store in session the primary keys for when they are needed as foreign keys. Currently, for every time a new record is inserted, there is one call per that record to the corresponding sequence/ PK. I am looking for a way to cut down on the number of calls made by reserving a range and I can only think to modify the existing.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot lock a DB2 `SEQUENCE`, nor do you need to. The DB2 engine handles sequence synchronization and guarantees that each concurrent sessions receives non-conflicting sequence values.

For batch inserts you can set the sequence cache to the batch size, which significantly improves concurrency.

You can obtain the last generated sequence value for reuse as a foreign key value in multiple ways. The simplest is to use the `PREVIOUS VALUE FOR <sequence name>` expression and store the result in an application variable. An alternative is to query the *data change table* of the `INSERT`:

```
SELECT id INTO :my_fk_variable FROM FINAL TABLE (
 INSERT INTO my_table (id, something) 
 VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR my_sequence, 'whatever'))
```

Comment: See above. The procurement of the range of primary keys are to be one call and the inserts all another in batch. I am doing these separately to be able to cache the values in the app for defining foreign keys. At the end of processing all of the new records, I'd end up with a populated Map<String,Long>.

Comment: You don't need to cache the sequence values in the application -- it is done for you by DB2. If you do that in the application, you're wasting memory and CPU cycles. If you want this in the application, don't use the database `SEQUENCE` -- but then your implementation is practically guaranteed to be slower and less reliable.

Comment: Then explain how I would be applying the foreign keys to the newly updated/ inserted records without making another call that I cannot easily determine why it fails if it does?

Comment: You don't need to do "another call", not sure even to what. You can still store the sequence values in your application for later use if you wish, the difference is that you obtain them _after_ and _as a part of_ each insert, not _before_.

Answer (score 1):

Use randomly generated 16 byte primary keys.  Generate them in your Java code.   No need to look them up.   Absurdly low risk of collisions.  Master-master replication friendly.   Never any locking.   Batch as many as you want.  Fantastic performance within indexes (excellent key dispersion).

Also known as: GUID's or UUID's.

Comment: It is indeed a good option. One would still need to make sure the application handles duplicate key exceptions gracefully.

Comment: But it's so unlikely.  According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack, even after a trillion rows are created your risk of a *single* collision is less than one trillionth of a percent.

Comment: I can only say this after the wise man: “In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they are not.” Remember also the "Black swan" theory.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

1. Start of transaction
2. Alter sequence (Increment by No. of rows) [1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_altersequence.dita)
3. Store in a temp variable the last value.
4. return the temp variable.
5. End of transaction.

Comment: I want to make certain of this: The transaction will block any concurrent attempts to alter the same sequence.

Comment: It will defer the concurrent. How many of such transactions do you expect in a small time interval?

Comment: Assuming altering the current system I am working on, 4 clusters, 4 JVMs apiece, and 8 threads, there is some potential for a significant number of them.